# node.js module for reading redis key as stream

Tags: node.js, redis, stream

I have problem in reading keys in Redis on Node.js and them save data to mongodb.
Because the number of keys is huge ( 1.3 million), this causes JavaScript heap out of memory.

Could anyone suggest me some Node.js module to read Redis keys as stream or some other solution to this problem, so I could avoid this issue.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ioredis` (https://github.com/luin/ioredis) does support streams.

Example with `SCAN` from their readme.

```
var redis = new Redis();
// Create a readable stream (object mode)
var stream = redis.scanStream();
var keys = [];
stream.on('data', function (resultKeys) {
  // `resultKeys` is an array of strings representing key names
  for (var i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++) {
    keys.push(resultKeys[i]);
  }
});
stream.on('end', function () {
  console.log('done with the keys: ', keys);
});
```